# Hash function to map k nearest data into same bucket

Tags: java, python, algorithm, hashmap, hashtable

I have an array say `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 12, 6, 200, 300, 500]`. I am trying to develop a hash function such that all elements separated by the same distance `k`should collide at the same position in output array forming a linked list at that location with the header of the linked list at that location. This will help to find the nearest elements based on distance using the hash function. I tried very simple hash function `h(j)=int(j/k)` where `k` is the distance for e.g if `k=5` then the colliding points would be like this `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] [6, 10] [12] [200] [300] [500]`.
My aim is to give two numbers to hash function for e.g. `1` and `2` and they should return me the same position `0` in the array telling me they are the nearest neighbor.
This should run in Expected theta n space and time complexity.

Comment: i need alaso equivalent hash function such that near number should map to same location in output array. eg.[1,2,3,4,,100,200,150] ==> [[1,2,3,4],[100,200,150]]. Did u find anything? it will be grate help if someone refer best resource for that.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you plan on having the same numbers in multiple buckets, this will not be possible.  Even in your own example, 5 is in a different bucket than 6 but is actually closer to 6 than 10 which is grouped with 6.

If you allow the same number to appear in multiple buckets, then you could get a "close neighbour" grouping based on a threshold distance but your result would look more like this (assuming max distance < 5):

```
[1,2,3,4,5] [2,3,4,5,6] [6,10] [10,12] [200] [300] [500]
```